# Using Angular Bootstrap tabs, is it possible to dynamically add tabs with content from a component?

Tags: angular, dynamic, tabs, components

I am looking at this example:

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/components/tabs?tab=overview#tabs-dynamic

This is nearly what I need but the dynamic tabs contain only strings in 'content'.

```
interface ITab {
  title: string;
  content: string;
  removable: boolean;
  disabled: boolean;
  active?: boolean;
  customClass?: string;
}

tabs: ITab[] = [
{ title: 'Dynamic Title 1', content: 'Dynamic content 1', removable: false, disabled: false},
{ title: 'Dynamic Title 2', content: 'Dynamic content 2', removable: false, disabled: false},
{ title: 'Dynamic Title 3', content: 'Dynamic content 3', removable: true, disabled: false} ];
```

I want to be able to inject components into these dynamic tabs.

Can anyone suggest how this might be achieved?

Comment: refer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47917969/valor-software-ngx-bootstrap-put-a-component-inside-dynamically-created-content?rq=2

Comment: You can use Dinamic component loader https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader (relevant for newest versions). For older versions there is a simillar aproach, try to google it.

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed a duplicate that I couldn't find searching. There is an answer included.

[Valor-software/ngx-bootstrap put a component inside dynamically created content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47917969/valor-software-ngx-bootstrap-put-a-component-inside-dynamically-created-content?rq=2)